# Postinstallation script exit error 10: ucf fails

Tags: 16.04, scripts, r, configure

When trying to install R on Ubuntu 16.04 xenial, I'm stuck because `r-base-core` can't be configured. I'm using the [common manual](https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-install-r-on-linux-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus/). 
Apparently the postinstallation script fails when ucf is supposed to do something. When adding the `-x` argument to the postinstallation script:

```
Setting up r-base-core (3.3.2-1xenial0) ...
+ dpkg-maintscript-helper mv_conffile /etc/bash_completion.d/R /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/R -- configure 
+ mktemp
+ tmpRenviron=/tmp/tmp.MANJybxXxQ
+ chmod 0644 /tmp/tmp.MANJybxXxQ
+ cat /usr/lib/R/etc/Renviron.ucf
+ paperconf
+ papersize=a4
+ perl -p -i -e s{^R_PAPERSIZE_USER=\$\{R_PAPERSIZE\}}
        {R_PAPERSIZE_USER=\$\{R_PAPERSIZE-'a4'\}}x /tmp/tmp.MANJybxXxQ
+ ucf /tmp/tmp.MANJybxXxQ /etc/R/Renviron
dpkg: error processing package r-base-core (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
```

Based on other posts I found online regarding ucf problems in postinstallation scripts, I added debug level 3 to the ucf-line in the posinstallation script. This is what the console looks like now:

```
+ dpkg-maintscript-helper mv_conffile /etc/bash_completion.d/R /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/R -- configure 
+ mktemp
+ tmpRenviron=/tmp/tmp.LsP3FSBIRI
+ chmod 0644 /tmp/tmp.LsP3FSBIRI
+ cat /usr/lib/R/etc/Renviron.ucf
+ paperconf
+ papersize=a4
+ perl -p -i -e s{^R_PAPERSIZE_USER=\$\{R_PAPERSIZE\}}
        {R_PAPERSIZE_USER=\$\{R_PAPERSIZE-'a4'\}}x /tmp/tmp.LsP3FSBIRI
+ ucf --debug=3 /tmp/tmp.LsP3FSBIRI /etc/R/Renviron
The new start file is      `/tmp/tmp.LsP3FSBIRI\'
The destination is         `/etc/R/Renviron\' (`\/etc\/R\/Renviron\')
The history is kept under  \'/tmp\'
The file may be cached at \'/var/lib/ucf/cache/:etc:R:Renviron\'
The destination file does not exist.
The old md5sum does not exist.
The new file exists, and has md5sum:
7c899e0d9d42df33d5dfd303ef43c46b  /tmp/tmp.LsP3FSBIRI
Historical md5sums are not available
The new start file is      `/tmp/tmp.LsP3FSBIRI\'
The destination is         `/etc/R/Renviron\' (`\/etc\/R\/Renviron\')
The history is kept under  \'/tmp\'
The file may be cached at \'/var/lib/ucf/cache/:etc:R:Renviron\'
dpkg: error processing package r-base-core (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 20
```

I don't know where to go from here.

**Tl;dr:** I seem to have a similar problem as discussed [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2129391), except that the solution doesn't work. The command

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install r-base-core
```

returns

```
E: Internal Error, No file name for r-base-core:amd64
```

and the command

```
sudo sed -i 's/\tucf/\t#ucf/' /var/lib/dpkg/info/r-base-core.postinst
sudo apt-get -f install
```

results as usual in

```
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same situation on Ubuntu 20.04 (with different packages, but `ucf` was at the root of the problem - in fact, it seemed to be `ucf` failing to access its own `debconf` configuration).

This worked for me:

```
sudo apt --reinstall install ucf
```

It looks like the `ucf` installation had become corrupt somehow.